# Using eclipse GUI to Birt parameters, how do I add a custom property?

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin, birt

Inside eclipse I have a birt xml that I want to modify with a custom property. If I add it to the xml directly and our user modifies the file using the gui, all changes added to the xml directly are lost. Is there a way to add it to the gui or add a property to the xml so that it will persist?

```
    <scalar-parameter name="scStartDate" id="64">
        <property name="CUSTOM">field i want to add gets removed on save in gui</property>
        <text-property name="helpText">Select a start date</text-property>
        <text-property name="promptText">Start Date</text-property>
        <property name="valueType">static</property>
        <property name="dataType">string</property>
        <property name="distinct">true</property>
        <simple-property-list name="defaultValue">
            <value type="javascript">BirtDateTime.addDay(BirtDateTime.today(), -7) </value>
        </simple-property-list>
        <list-property name="selectionList"/>
        <property name="paramType">simple</property>
        <property name="controlType">text-box</property>
        <structure name="format">
            <property name="category">Unformatted</property>
        </structure>
    </scalar-parameter>
```

[image: Birt Editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a native custom property feature in Eclipse GUI for any report element, see the example below.

[image]

Then you can access this property for each parameter in java, JSP or a script with this method:

```
IParameterDefnBase.getUserPropertyValue()
```